# Blender 2.90 - paint specular but see final result

Tags: materials, texture-painting

is it possible to see the final result instead of seeing the texture actually painted ?

I mean, if I select specular (black texture at first), then the object I paint turns black

...instead of being displayed as a final material result (diffuse + specular + ...)

pretty annoying

is there an option to see the final material result ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something I'm doing when texture painting (well, always, but especially when texture painting) is using multiple 3D viewports, with different settings:

[image]

Typically, I'll have an editing window and a display window.  The editing window is what you'd expect, just basic settings.  The display window is likely to be a rendered preview, with overlays disabled.  (I might make occasional changes to it.  I typically use local collection displays for the viewports as well.)

I'm likely, when texture painting, to also have an image editor viewport open, as well as a shader viewport.

If you texture paint like this, you can see you texture painting in one viewport, while you see the rendered effects of that texture painting in the other viewport.  However, your rendered preview won't show the effects during a stroke, only after the stroke.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I am making video games, so the goal is to see it real time shading like

Comment: this is not what I asked...I want to see the output of the shader, not one texture at a time...there is no need to set a "viewport shading" view

Comment: @phil123 The output of the shader is on the rendered preview, on the left of my picture.

Answer (score 0):

the way to achieve what I wanted was to use HDRI images and a background node in a world shader

I have no idea how/why it works, but suddenly, the final shader output was rendered in the viewport instead of the currently drawn on texture

[image]